# how can we make a Zip Code and postal code mandatory on checkout page in magento

Tags: magento-1.7

I am trying to make a zip code and postal code mandatory for shipping and billing information but i am not success kindly provide some solutions.

Comment: Default magento billing.phtml file already contains validation class validate-zip-international this is not working for you?

Comment: The magento default theme already supports this.

Answer (score 15):

Go to

> System->Configuration->Default->General->Countries Options

Multiselect Box called ‘Postal Code is Optional for the following countries’.

Select the countries you want the field as optional.

As far as concerned with code changes, It is always recommended to follow inbuilt features instead of code changes.

Comment: OP don't want to make field as optional

Answer (score 1):

The other way is to add `required-entry` class name to the fields by visiting the templates.

Comment: I think it's `required-entry`.

Answer (score 1):

their will be a text box for the zip code their please add "required-entry" in the class attribute of the zipcode textbox.then it is done

for eg.

```
<input type="text" title="<?php echo $this->__('Zip/Postal Code') ?>" name="billing[postcode]" id="billing:postcode" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getAddress()->getPostcode()) ?>" class="required-entry input-text validate-zip-international <?php echo $this->helper('customer/address')->getAttributeValidationClass('postcode') ?>" />
```

see i had added required-entry in class above

Comment: How can i get checkout page shipping zip code?