# How to remove Zip/postal code from customer registration form in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, php, registration

I want to know how to remove **Zip/postal** code from customer **registration form** in Magento 2?

Answer (score 1):

Copy file from 
`vendor\magento\module-customer\view\frontend\templates\form\register.phtml` and paste this path

```
app\design\frontend\Vendor\theme\Magento_Customer\templates\form\register.phtml
```

and comment this code or and `remove line 104 to 109`

and go to stores->Configuration->general->general->country options -> Zip/Postal Code is Optional for
here is you can remove zip code
and please check url to remove validation 
[Remove postal code required](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/143353/remove-postal-code-required?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)